# RasEnumConnections function in JNA is returning incomplete data. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, jna

RasEnumConnections function which realized in JNA is returning incomplete data.
What wrong? This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connected();
}

private static void Connected () {
    boolean state = false;
    ArrayList<String> connectedNames = new ArrayList<>();
    IntByReference lpcb = new IntByReference(0);
    IntByReference lpcConnections = new IntByReference(0);
    Rasapi32.INSTANCE.RasEnumConnections(null, lpcb,lpcConnections);

    WinRas.RASCONN conn = new WinRas.RASCONN();
    conn.dwSize = lpcb.getValue();
    WinRas.RASCONN[] connArray;
    if(lpcConnections.getValue() > 0)
        connArray = (WinRas.RASCONN[])conn.toArray(lpcConnections.getValue());
    else
        connArray = (WinRas.RASCONN[])conn.toArray(1);
    System.out.println("lpcb: " + lpcb.getValue() + " lpcConnections: " + lpcConnections.getValue() + " RASCONN Size: " + conn.dwSize);
    int error = Rasapi32.INSTANCE.RasEnumConnections(connArray, lpcb,lpcConnections);

    if(error == WinError.ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("Entry name: " + Native.toString(connArray[0].szEntryName)
        + " Guid string: " + connArray[0].guidEntry.toGuidString());
        System.out.println(connArray[0].guidEntry.Data1);
        System.out.println(connArray[0].guidEntry.Data2);
        System.out.println(connArray[0].guidEntry.Data3);

    }
    else System.out.println("Error: " + error);

    WinRas.RASENTRY.ByReference entry = getPhoneBookEntry("test1");
    if(entry != null) {
        System.out.println("test1 guid: "+ entry.guidId.toGuidString());
        System.out.println(entry.guidId.Data1);
        System.out.println(entry.guidId.Data2);
        System.out.println(entry.guidId.Data3);
    }

    else System.out.println("Error: " + Native.getLastError());

    }
}
```

[image: In debugger:]

Char array szEntryName contains only 3 last chars of connection name. (Connection name is "test1")

Comment: A hint appears in the output of your debugger: the Java structure is auto-allocated at 1392 bytes, while your structure size is 1388 bytes. Another hint appears if you look at the bytes representing the missing `t` (0x74) and `e` (0x65) and see that they appear in the address of the `hrasconn` field.

Comment: What is your OS bitness and your JVM bitness?  I suspect JNA is assuming a 64-bit `HANDLE` in the structure when you have an actual 32-bit `LPHANDLE` returned from the OS.

Comment: OS - 64 bit. JVM - 64 bit. If I pass "conn" structure with auto-allocated size (1392 byte) RasEnumConnections is returning 632 error...

Comment: So if you replace `conn.dwSize = lpcb.getValue();` with `conn.dwSize = conn.size();` it gives 632 error?

Comment: Yes, in this case error = 632

Comment: Try both `conn.dwSize = conn.size();` and `lpcb = new IntByReference(conn.size());`.  You need to both set the first element size to the JNA auto-allocated size _and_ tell `RasEnumConnections` that size.

Comment: I tried this several minutes ago, but result is the same )

Comment: If you have more than one result you'd need to set it to a multiple. I've typed the full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've noted in the comments, the debug output gives you a strong hint at what's happening.  The missing "t" and "e" characters appear as 0x74 and 0x65 in the midst of what JNA expects to be a 64-bit pointer.   The logical conclusion is that Windows is returning a 32-bit pointer followed by the string, 4 bytes earlier than JNA expected.

`RasEnumConnections` states a few things regarding the buffer you are passing as `connArray`:

> On input, an application must set the dwSize member of the first
>   RASCONN structure in the buffer to sizeof(RASCONN) in order to
>   identify the version of the structure being passed.

In your sample code above you are leaving this value the same as the value from the initial return.  This is specifying the "wrong" version of the structure.  Instead, you should set the `dwSize` member to the size you want in your JNA structure:

```
conn.dwSize = conn.size();
```

Actually, the constructor for RASCONN [sets this for you](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/7ac44fee3d6b0e47de6d5d10c32be258b9ed1bef/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinRas.java#L285)! So you actually don't have to do this.  But in your code sample above, you are overwriting what was pre-set; just delete your `conn.dwSize` line.

Note that since you are now requesting a (4-bytes per array element) larger buffer by definining the structure size, you also need to pass the increased size in the (second) `RasEnumConnections()` call.  It's set as the number of elements times the (smaller) structure size, but you should reset to the number of elements times the (larger) size like this:

```
lpcb.setValue(conn.size() * lpcConnections.getValue());
```

prior to fetching the full array.  Otherwise you'll get the error 632 (Incorrect Structure Size).

For reference (or perhaps a suitable replacement for your own code), take a look at the code as implemented in the [`getRasConnection(String connName)` method in JNA's Rasapi32Util.java class](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/7ac44fee3d6b0e47de6d5d10c32be258b9ed1bef/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Rasapi32Util.java#L144).

Comment: Does it still break on 64 bit? Could be a bug in JNA.

Comment: Yes. I get 632 on 64 bit... ( Probably JNA uses 32 bit Rasapi32.dll with 64 JRE and 64 bit win 10... I tried to load 32 bit jnidispatch.dll by copying it from win32-x86 to win32-x86-64 directory but I got exception: `Exception in thread "main" Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform` I also tried to set path to 64 bit system libraries: `NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("Rasapi32", "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64");`  but in this case I got exception too: `Unable to load library 'Rasapi32':
%1 not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: You may be able to create your own version of `RASCONN` that places a 4-byte value where the current `HANDLE` is, to work around the problem on 64-bit. (I still think it should be `HANDLEByReference` but that wouldn't change the bitness.)  You may wish to bring this question up on the JNA Mailing List.

Comment: I added the constructor to my own RASCONN structure `public RASCONN(int alignType) {
            super(alignType);
            dwSize = size();
        }` and  passed 1 to this constructor `Rasapi32.RASCONN rasconn = new Rasapi32.RASCONN(1);` and connection name became full :) Guid is still incorrect...